# find the general case of while loops

Tags: python, list, loops, numpy, while-loop

I am working with a python list as the following code:

```
x=[0.1,0.1,0.1]
dx=0.1
R=1
while x[0] < R:
  while x[1] < R:
    if np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2) < R:
      x[2] = x[2] + dx           
     counter = counter + 1
    else:

       x[1] = x[1] + dx
       x[0]= dx
 print(counter)
  x[0] = x[0] + dx
  x[1] = dx
```

But for a bigger list for example:

```
x=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
dx=0.1
#we have to add another while loop 
while x[0]<R:
     while x[1]<R:
         while x[2]<R:
           if np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2) < R:
                  x[3] = x[3] + dx           
                  counter = counter + 1
            else:

                   x[2] = x[2] + dx
                   x[1]= dx
         x[1] = x[1] + dx
         x[2] = dx
    x[0]=x[0]+dx
    x[1]=dx
```

and so on 
What I am trying to to do is to find a way to implement this code for any list of any number of element (the general case) 
But I cannot find out how to transform these while loops to any number of dimesnions (number of elements in the array)

and just in case this code will do the following:

```
example: for dx=0.1 and R=1 and we start with 0.1

start with x=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1] (after the first loop) x=[0.9, 0.1, 0.1] And then [0.1, 0.2, 0.1] And so on until [0.9, 0.9, 0.1] After we will get [0.1,0.1,0.2] And we will start again with [0.2, 0.1, 0.2] and so on
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what you intend to do in the first place ? **Usually**, when you have more than 2 nested loops in your code, there's a better way to organize your code.

Comment: At a glance, this looks like a pretty straightforward recursive function.

Comment: That said, is it correct/intended for the `if np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2) < R:` line to be identical between both cases?

Comment: example: for dx=0.1 and R=1 and we start with 0.1

this is what I am trying to do: 
 start with x=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1] (after the first loop) x=[0.9, 0.1, 0.1] And then [0.1, 0.2, 0.1] And so on until [0.9, 0.9, 0.1] After we will get [0.1,0.1,0.2] And we will start again with [0.2, 0.1, 0.2] and so on

Comment: Grokking that involves paying more attention to the problem space (rather than to Python syntax/logic/best-practices) than I'm willing to provide free-of-charge at this time in the morning. Can you focus the question around the Python side of it, isolating out the math/logic?

Comment: sorry this was a mistake in the second code, it should be 
     if np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2+x[3]**2) < R

Comment: the original problem is much more complicated than that, I am trying to approximate the volume of hyper spheres by putting hyper cubes inside of them, and the list x represents the number of dimensions

Comment: Apart from the `np.sqrt` I don't see any use of `numpy`.  This looks like a 'plain' python list and iteration problem.  I would also recommend using `math.sqrt` instead of `np.sqrt`.  That `if` context requires scalars, and `math` functions are faster for that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments, there's almost certainly a better way to do this. However, this (quickly chucked together) recursive function will do it and edit your array x in place

```
def f(x, dx, n=0):
    if n == len(x) - 2:
        while x[n] < R:
           if np.sqrt(sum(i**2 for i in x[:-1])) < R:  # I think you mean this
              x[n+1] += dx           
              counter += 1
           else:
              x[n] += dx
              x[n-1] = dx
    else:
        while x[n] < R:
            f(x, dx, n+1)  # recursion
            x[n] += dx
            x[n+1] = dx
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I am looking for, it is giving me different results. I will try to edit it to get the thing I wanted.
But thank you anyway